# Convergence of a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Consider a filtered probability space ($\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}$) and a random variable $X$ defined on $\Omega$ with values in a set $E$.

We consider the process $X_t = \mathbb{E}[ X | \mathcal{F}_t]$ and the question is the following:

What conditions should be put on $\mathcal{F_t}$ so that $X_t$ has continuous paths $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. That is to say

$X_t = \lim_{s\rightarrow t} X_s$ a.s

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale. Fix $t>0$. By the martingale convergence theorem, there exists $Y \in L^1$ such that

$$X_s = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_s) \to Y, \qquad s \uparrow t$$

in $L^1$ and almost surely. Using the tower property, we find

$$\mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X_s = \mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s), \qquad s<t$$

and therefore

$$\int_F Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X_t \, d\mathbb{P}$$

for any $F \in \mathcal{F}_s$. This implies

$$\int_F Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X_t \, d\mathbb{P}$$

for any $F \in \sigma(F_s; s <t)=: \mathcal{F}_{t-}$. As $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t-}$-measurable, we conclude

$$Y = \mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-})$$

This yields the (necessary and sufficient) condition for left-continuity of the process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$:

$$X_t \stackrel{!}{=} Y=\mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-}) = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-}) \tag{1}$$

A similar reasoning shows that

$$X_t \stackrel{!}{=} \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{t+}) \tag{2}$$

with $\mathcal{F}_{t+} := \bigcap_{s>t} \mathcal{F}_s$ ensures the right-continuity of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

Consequently, we conclude that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is (a.s.) continuous if and only if $(1)$ and $(2)$ are satisfied. This is in particular the case if

$$\mathcal{F}_{t-} = \mathcal{F}_t = \mathcal{F}_{t+}$$

for any $t \geq 0$.

Comment: Nice proof ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Moja $\mathbb{E}(X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X_s$ follows directly from the definition of $X_t$ and the tower property. To prove $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X_s$ note that $\mathbb{E}(X_{t-1/n} \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X_s$ means that$$\forall F \in \mathcal{F}_s: \quad \int_F X_{t-1/n} \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X_s \, d\mathbb{P}.$$ Since $X_{t-1/n} \to Y$ in $L^1$ we get $$\forall F \in \mathcal{F}_s: \quad \int_F Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_F X_s \, d\mathbb{P},$$ i.e. $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = X_s$.

Comment: How do we know that $\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{F}_{t})$ is right-continous? I think we need this to use Doobs second convergence therorem. I suppose we can find a modification that is right-contious but I far as I understand thats as good as it gets.

Comment: @Maxed I don't understand your comment. Where am I claiming that $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_t)$ is right-continuous?

Comment: When you use Doobs martingale convergence theorem or is that not a condition?

Comment: @Maxed I see, you are right... seems that I was too sloppy there. I will think about it.

Comment: Why do you have the $!$ above the equalities?

Comment: @Probably We showed that $$\lim_{s \downarrow t} X_s = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{t+})$$ and $$\lim_{s \uparrow t} X_s = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-}).$$ Consequently, $s \mapsto X_s$ is continuous at $s=t$ if, and only if, $$\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{t+}) = X_t =  \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-}).$$